# Split an NSString at the first capital letter

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have a string like this `@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzA"`. As you can see, `A` is at the end. How can I find the first capital letter and split the strings:

```
NSString *lower = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
NSString *upper = @"A";
```

The string in the beginning is static so the capital letter could be ANYTHING. Will this scanner help?

```
NSString *String = titleLabelLatestNews.text;

NSScanner *stringScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:String];    
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] init];

while ([stringScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

    [stringScanner scanUpToString:@"url=\"" intoString:Nil];

    [stringScanner scanUpToString:@"/>" intoString:&content];
}
```

For another example,  `@"this is all lower case letters I am awesome";` should become two strings, `@"this is all lower case letters";` and `@"I am awesome";`

Get the idea? Anything before the Capital Letter goes to a string and anything after goes to another string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `NSScanner` will do the trick for you, yes. You just need to create an `NSCharacterSet` consisting of the capital letters, then use [`scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString:)

```
NSString * s = @"this is all lower case letters I am awesome";
NSScanner * scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:s];
NSString * firstPart;
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet]
                        intoString:&firstPart];
NSString * secondPart = [s substringFromIndex:[scanner scanLocation]];
```

Comment: If you are happy to stop on all uppercase letters, not just the Latin A-Z, then `NSCharacterSet`'s `uppercaseLetterCharacterSet` will do the job - no need to build a set.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using NSScanner, use `scanCharactersFromSet:intoString:` where the NSCharacterSet is lowercase characters only.

What I would personally do, if anyone cares, is call `rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.uppercaseLetterCharacterSet()...)` and derive the resulting substrings from there.

Comment: You don't like `NSScanner`?

Comment: @JoshCaswell It isn't a matter of liking. I simply mean that my response assumes that use of NSScanner is built into the premise of the question. If it were my own code, though, I would do it completely differently.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. I don't read the question as being settled on `NSScanner` as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to use NSString's `rangeOfCharacterFromSet`

```
 NSString *lowerCaseString=@"";
 NSString *upperCaseString=@"";
 NSString *stringToSplit = titleLabelLatestNews.text;
 NSRange capitalRange=[stringToSplit rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet]];
 if (capitalRange.location == NSNotFound) {
    lowerCaseString=stringToSplit;
 }
 else if (capitalRange.location ==0 ) {
    upperCaseString=stringToSplit;
 }
 else {
    lowerCaseString=[stringToSplit substringToIndex:capitalRange.location-1];
    upperCaseString=[stringToSplit substringFromIndex:capitalRange.location];
 }

 NSLog(@"lower case string=%@ uppercase=%@",lowerCaseString,upperCaseString);
```

Comment: FYI, this will throw an NSRangeException if the first letter of the string is capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the regular expression solution:

1. Use `NSRegularExpression`
2. The pattern `@"([^A-Z]*)([A-Z].*)"` will match what you want if you are only interested in A-Z as uppercase characters (see below for unicode change). Broken down this is two group, `(...)`, one for before one for after; first group - anything which is not uppercase, `[^A-Z]`, zero or more times, `*`; second group - an uppercase letter, `[A-Z]`, followed by anything, `.*`.
3. Use `firstMatchInString:options:range:`; the `NSTextCheckingResult` will contain the ranges of the two matched groups.

If you wish to allow for Unicode's myriad of uppercase and titlecase letters just change `A-Z` above to `\\p{Lu}\\p{Lt}` (make sure you type the double-backslashes, you are passing a backslash to `NSRegularExpression`). Those two are all the Unicode uppercase letters, `\\p{Lu}`, and all the title case letters, `\\p{Lt}`.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Throwing one more solution into the mix utilizing `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` to split the string into multiple arrays (i.e. more than 2 if needed):

```
// Separate the "sentence" into components separated
// by the characters in the uppercase character set
NSMutableArray *sentenceArray = [[sentence componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet]] mutableCopy];

// Get the first sentence "segment", i.e. the sentenceArray's
// first object
NSString *segment = [sentenceArray objectAtIndex:0];

// Keep track of the character count with a variable
int characterCount = (int)segment.length;

// Then starting from sentenceArray's index 1, go through
// the rest of sentenceArray's indices
for (int i = 1 ; i < sentenceArray.count ; i ++) {

    // Append that "separator" character to the segment at the
    // current index by accessing the character before the current segment
    segment = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [sentence characterAtIndex:characterCount]]stringByAppendingString:[sentenceArray objectAtIndex:i]];

    // Replace the object at the current index with this new segment
    // string
    [sentenceArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:segment];

     // Increment the character count
    characterCount += segment.length;
}

NSLog(@"%@", sentenceArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Find index of first capital letter
NSInteger index = ^NSInteger{
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < string.length; ++i) {
        unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') { return i; }
    }

    return string.length; // No capital letter, take the entire string
}();

NSLog(@"lower = %@", [string substringToIndex:index]);
NSLog(@"upper = %@", [string substringFromIndex:index]);
```

Comment: Why would you create an anonymous Block for this? The `for` loop is fine by itself.

Comment: @JoshCaswell it isn't, if you think about it. Blocks help improve locality. It may be not neccessary in this case, but absolutely not "absurd". More like a personal preference IMHO.

Comment: You have to create a variable to contain the found index either way, and everything else is scoped to the `for` loop. There's no gain, just extra syntactical elements to confuse your readers.

Comment: It's not just about the variable's locality, it's the logic's locality. Think as if the block could be refactored into a method, but a one-time used method is a bit bloated.

Comment: If you don't assign the Block to anything, you can't reuse it. Talking about the raw text, you can copy-paste the loop as easily as you can the Block.

Comment: Don't know what you mean. I don't mean to reuse it. By using a block, the logic inside can be thought of separately from the rest of the code (e.g `index = ^{ ..... }()`, you don't have to care about what's inside the `{}`), and thus reduces complexity of the code. Its functions is the same as a method: reducing complexity, except that it is not reusable.